How to use GraphQL to retrieve only one field based on compound query
I am working with the Graphiql at https://data.rcsb.org/graphql/index.html?query=%7B%0A%20%20polymer_entity_instances(instance_ids%3A%20%5B%221S0H.A%22%5D)%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rcsb_id%0A%0A%20%20%20%20rcsb_polymer_instance_feature%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20provenance_source%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D.  I am using the query:
{
  polymer_entity_instances(instance_ids: ["1S0H.A"])
  {
    rcsb_id

    rcsb_polymer_instance_feature {
      provenance_source
      name
      type
    }
  }
}

And am receiving the response:
{
  "data": {
    "polymer_entity_instances": [
      {
        "rcsb_id": "1S0H.A",
        "rcsb_polymer_instance_feature": [
          {
            "provenance_source": "CATH",
            "name": "Globins",
            "type": "CATH"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "SCOPe",
            "name": "Hemoglobin, alpha-chain",
            "type": "SCOP"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "SCOP2",
            "name": "Globins",
            "type": "SCOP2_FAMILY"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "SCOP2",
            "name": "Globin-like",
            "type": "SCOP2_SUPERFAMILY"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "ECOD",
            "name": "PF00042",
            "type": "ECOD"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PROMOTIF",
            "name": "helix",
            "type": "HELIX_P"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PROMOTIF",
            "name": "helix",
            "type": "HELIX_P"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PROMOTIF",
            "name": "helix",
            "type": "HELIX_P"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PROMOTIF",
            "name": "helix",
            "type": "HELIX_P"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PROMOTIF",
            "name": "helix",
            "type": "HELIX_P"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PROMOTIF",
            "name": "helix",
            "type": "HELIX_P"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PROMOTIF",
            "name": "helix",
            "type": "HELIX_P"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PROMOTIF",
            "name": "helix",
            "type": "HELIX_P"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PROMOTIF",
            "name": "unassigned secondary structure",
            "type": "UNASSIGNED_SEC_STRUCT"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PDB",
            "name": "ligand HEM",
            "type": "BINDING_SITE"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PDB",
            "name": "Molprobity bond angle outlier",
            "type": "ANGLE_OUTLIER"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PDB",
            "name": "Molprobity bond distance outlier",
            "type": "BOND_OUTLIER"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PDB",
            "name": "Molprobity Ramachandran outlier",
            "type": "RAMACHANDRAN_OUTLIER"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PDB",
            "name": "Molprobity rotamer outlier",
            "type": "ROTAMER_OUTLIER"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "PDB",
            "name": "Real space R-value Z score > 2",
            "type": "RSRZ_OUTLIER"
          },
          {
            "provenance_source": "biojava-7.0.1",
            "name": "Unbound ASA",
            "type": "ASA"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Which contains the information that I need.  However, it also contains a bunch of other information and I am having trouble figuring out how to filter the results.  All I really need is 'name' from this instance:
          {
            "provenance_source": "SCOP2",
            "name": "Globins",
            "type": "SCOP2_FAMILY"
          }

I have tried adding the below conditions several ways but I have not been able to figure out the correct syntax.  How can I get this to work?
provenance_source:"SCOP2"
type: "SCOP2_FAMILY"


The rcsb_polymer_instance_feature field that returns the list of features does not have any arguments that could be used for filtering in that schema. You can try filing a feature request, or you just continue client-side filtering
